# Computing Area of the Window - Error in Formula

Tags: c#, numbers, integer, formula

I am having a bit of a problem with my program. Basically, I have to create a program that finds the area of a window (e.g. a glass window). The formula is Area = Height * Width and so that is what I have entered. However, the outcome is not actually answering Height * Width. If I enter the two numbers as the same (for example, 3 * 3) the answer will be correct (9). On the other hand, if I enter two different numbers (for example, 4 * 5) the answer is not correct (it will say the answer to the previous example is 25, it should be 20). Can anyone help me understand why it is doing this and help me fix the problem?

P.S I have only just started using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express for computing at school. That is why it is fairly simple.

```
using System;

namespace FindTheArea
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {               
            string temporary;
            double Height;
            double Width;
            double Area;

            Console.WriteLine("Find The Area");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the height below");
            temporary = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Width below");
            temporary = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Clear();

            Height = double.Parse(temporary);
            Width = double.Parse(temporary);

            Area = (Height * Width);

            Console.WriteLine("The area is...");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(Area+"cm2");

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

I now understand where I have gone wrong. But how do I fix it?

Comment: You overwrite the values of `temporary`. You should use two different variables to store the two values you enter.

Comment: Now would be a fantastic time to learn how to use a debugger. Microsoft Visual C# Express has a fantastic debugger that you should learn to love.

Answer (score 6):

```
Height = double.Parse(temporary);
Width = double.Parse(temporary);
```

There is an obvious problem here. The behavior of `double.Parse()` is deterministic, so you are assigning the same value to `Height` and `Width`.

Comment: How do I fix this problem? Can you please tell me what to take out or what to add in?

Comment: @user, I usually don't do that in questions tagged `[homework]`, because it indicates you're learning the ropes, so a complete answer might actually be a disservice to you. It could prevent you from fully understanding the problem, as you certainly will if you ponder the issue from a logical standpoint. The other answers will get you on the right track.

Comment: OK. Well, thanks anyway! :) I have tried to change things around regarding the temporary as I understand that having a temporary for the height and a temporary for the width mean the same and therefore the first temporary is overwritten but I can't seem to change it to make that work. I have tried taking things away and (separately) adding some things in, but nothing seems to work. Thanks anyway, I'm sure I will work it out sometime! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the height below");

temporary = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Width below");

temporary = Console.ReadLine();
```

You're overwriting the first value of `temporary`. You should assign the entered values to two different variables.

```
string temporaryHeight;
string temporaryWidth;

Console.WriteLine("Please enter the height below");

temporaryHeight= Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Width below");

temporaryWidth= Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporary has the same value! Change one to temporary1 and the other to temporary2.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Console.WriteLine("Please enter the height below");

        temporary = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Width below");

        temporary = Console.ReadLine();
```

You're not storing the first value.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the height below");

    temporary = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Width below");

    temporary = Console.ReadLine();
```

You’re assigning the height value to temporary, then assigning the width value to temporary. This means you’ve lost the height value, as you've overwritten it.

Answer (score 0):

using System;

```
namespace FindTheArea
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double Height;
            double Width;
            double Area;

            Console.WriteLine("Find The Area");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the height below");
            Height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Width below");
            Width = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Clear();

            Area = (Height * Width);

            Console.WriteLine("The area is...");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(Area+"cm2");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: what is wrong with ? if i set Width and height i get correct answer about area value..

Comment: Didn't downvote, but some users discourage complete answers for homework.